# iframe breaks div sequence

Tags: html, iframe

I have a site (http://maladrerie.heliohost.org/mkh/index.html) using CSS to keep header, menu and footer fixed while the content scrolls. I am trying to add a photo page using an iframe and it works pretty well (I still need to tune it for different browsers).

But after the iframe the page stops displaying, which means that I lose my footer. The relevant code is (I think) in fotopag.php:

```
<div class="container">
   ... (header and menu)
 <div class="content">
  <iframe class="fotoframe" src="<?php print($foto) ; ?>"
  </iframe>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

The site is in Dutch but you can see that all pages have a footer except the page "Foto's". I have googled and tried everything I can think of, but am making no progress. 
One odd thing is that if I replace the php code with a fixed reference and save the page as HTML I still get no footer, but KompoZer (my HTML editor) does show the footer.

I'm probably missing something simple but pretty-please tell me what it is!

--- Derek

Comment: What the actual page you're having a problem on? I noticed some weird code on http://maladrerie.heliohost.org/mkh/fotopag.php?foto=2012_11_29_1: `<iframe class="fotoframe" iframe="" <="" src="fotos/2012_11_29_1.html">` check your PHP, it looks like you have a stray angled bracket somewhere.

Comment: <iframe class=fotoframe src="fotos/lijst.html"!!!!!! </iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser doesn't run PHP. It runs the HTML code *generated* by PHP. When you look at the PHP code, you're making it hard to debug what's wrong in the browser, because you're not seeing what the browser sees.

Instead, you should do a View Source in the browser so you can see what is actually happening. Your code should look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    ... (header and menu)
    <div class="content">
        <iframe class="fotoframe" src="someurl"
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Does the problem jump out at you now?

If it doesn't, take a close look at the `<iframe` line. See the problem now?

(Update: after writing this I see that you've already done the pure HTML test. Sorry I missed that! I'll leave the advice there for others who may run into similar problems. But did your HTML code have the same problem - the missing `>` on the `<iframe` line?)

Comment: Thanks a million! I'll go and write out one hundred times "I must balance my brackets"

Comment: Glad to help. Now don't forget to balance your quotes when you write that out! ;-)